# template error while templating string: unexpected char u with ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a ansible playbook with below tasks and when I run it, I get an error:

```
tasks:
     - shell: timeout 5 ps aux | grep app
       register: result
       ignore_errors: True

     - name: Run your shell command
       shell:  "(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com 'ls -1 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/stuff/*' | parallel -j20 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc.com:{} /data/records/')"
       when: result.rc != 124 && result.rc != 0
```

Error is:

```
{"msg": "The conditional check 'result.rc != 124 && result.rc != 0' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'&' at 23. String: {% if result.rc != 124 && result.rc != 0 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/proc/test.yml': line 10, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: copy files\n        ^ here\n"}
```

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
when:
  - result.rc != 124
  - result.rc != 0
```

or

```
when: (result.rc != 124) and (result.rc != 0)
```